# Pymc how to fix shape issues

Tags: python, pymc

I have data like this (there 5 different shops: 0 ,1,2,3,4)

```
    sales   shop
0   117       0
1   0         0
2   0         0
3   134       1
4   0         2
```

I need to determine distribution for sales for each of shop using Bayes approach

I also have the following code

```
with pm.Model(coords=dict(shop=range(5))) as model:
mu = pm.Uniform('mu', 0, 1)
p = pm.Beta('p', alpha=1, beta=1)  
likelihood = pm.ZeroInflatedPoisson("likelihood", p, mu,dims='shop',observed=data.sales.values)
```

but when I do

`with model: prior = pm.sample_prior_predictive()`

i have an error with shape, i don't know how to solve it, i know at.stack option but don't understand how to use it

ValueError: conflicting sizes for dimension 'store': length 800 on the data but length 5 on coordinate 'shop'

Comment: Please include the error message to help troubleshoot.

Comment: done it in the end of question

Comment: It's really not clear what code you're using here. If you use the data you've provided and the code you've provided do you get the error you describe? Can you clarify exactly the stacktrace error you get and the code you are running